# What is the common ancestor of humans and trilobites?

Tags: evolution, palaeontology

I have always been immensely fascinated by trilobites. What is the single common ancestor of humans and trilobites? Do we know? Do we have a name for it? Have we identified it?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). I suggest you start with the [wikipedia page for trilobites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilobite) and pay particular attention to the "Scientific classification" panel. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: try searching common ancestor of arthropods and vertebrates.

Comment: Thanks guys :) I have always been fascinated by science. I look forward to spending more time here on this wiki.